# Bootstrap 4 accordion with card-header active class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

is there a way to add active class to Bootstrap4 Accordion on when panel is collapsed?

I can see that there is no active class being added to card-header when panel is collapsed.

Many thanks!

Accordion code below

```
**<div id="accordion" role="tablist">  
  <div class="card">  
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">  
      <h5 class="mb-0">  
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">  
          Collapsible Group Item #1  
        </a>  
      </h5>  
    </div>  

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">  
      <div class="card-body">  
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.  
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
  <div class="card">  
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">  
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">  
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>  
      </h5>  
    </div>  
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">  
      <div class="card-body">  
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.  
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
  <div class="card">  
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">  
      <h5 class="mb-0">  
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">  
          Collapsible Group Item #3  
        </a>  
      </h5>  
    </div>  
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">  
      <div class="card-body">  
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.  
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>**
```

Comment: please share some code

Comment: When the panel is open it will have a class `show`. will that help in your case?

Comment: No content gets class 'show'. Card-header gets nothing but actually could add a class to the parent through jquery but how will I remove it when panel is closed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code above is pretty good with one exception. Instead of targeting parent class we need to target element above to add active class card-header.

Correct jquery is :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).prev().addClass('active-acc');
    });

    $('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).prev().removeClass('active-acc');
    });

});
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: When your code is better the _code above_, some day one must look for that other code [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48361705/456456) :-)

Answer (score 12):

If you only need to select the active tab for styling reasons in CSS, you can use this syntax:

```
.card-header .btn[aria-expanded=true] {
color: #fff;
background-color: #32bdb6;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's a good solution but it works fine for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });

    $('.collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

```css
.card.active > .card-header{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't know why but this doesn't work for me. Need to look into that more.